# how do I POST data to a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a wordpress plugin that can catch POST/GET requests to a certain URL from outside, such that I can have external PHP code POSTing data to the wordpress plugin, which the plugin can then further handle internally.

I don't want to create blog posts or pages from outside, I know the XML-RPC interface exists for that. I'm talking about posting data from outside into wordpress and then handling it further within a plugin.

I guess I could also directly connect to the WP DB but that is probably not a very clean solution and might break if I upgrade WP.

Comment: What do you mean catch POST/GET request? Isn't $_POST/$_GET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know about WordPress XMRPC: Your plugin can register own functions for XMLRPC that listen to the request then. You can send a POST request to the XMLRPC endpoint then and the plugin function will be triggered then.

The following code-example is a simple plugin class that registers a function to the XMLRPC endpoint `my.recieve`. It shows how the callback function is registered to that string:

```
/**
 * XML RPC Plugin
 */
return RecievePostPlugin::bootstrap();

class RecievePostPlugin
{
    private static $instance;
    public static function bootstrap()
    {
        if (null === $this->instance)
             $this->instance = new __CLASS__;
        return $this->instance; 
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('xmlrpc_methods', array($this, 'addXMLRPCActions'));
    }
    public function addXMLRPCActions(array $methods)
    {
        $methods['my.recieve'] = array($this, 'recieveXMLRPCAction');
        return $methods;
    }
    public function recieveXMLRPCAction(array $arguments)
    {
       // your code here, POST can be accessed via $_POST
    }
}
```

If you dislike the XMLRPC overhead, you can just create a PHP file part of your plugin and request it. Then you need to take care yourself to load all WP functions you might want to use (e.g. database access etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rewrite rule, redirecting some fanciful pretty URL to a file in your plugin's directory. And that file will have $_POST data. From the [Wordpress page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) describing WP_Rewrite:

```
function feed_dir_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'index.rdf' => 'index.php?feed=rdf',
        'index.xml' => 'index.php?feed=rss2',
        '(.+).xml' => 'index.php?feed=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

// Hook in.
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'feed_dir_rewrite' );
```